# Async/Await Method Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am working on MERN Stack Application(Mean,Express,ReactJS,NodeJS). I have one issue is that I have many more methods in mlcontroller.js page and I call some methods on REST API so I call that methods under that API from mlrouter.js but all that API is Async so currently API takes data slots vise means I give u an example that in one time take 100 data from first method and then pass to another method and pass from all methods again come to first method and take next 100 data and repeat same process again but I need to take all data in one time means untill one method will not complete not move on another method how's that possible with node js?

I place my code here :

**mlrouter.js**

```
  ensureApiAuthenticated,
  authController.checkReadOnlyUser,
  mlController.getAPIData,
  mlController.getData,
  mlController.getCRCDetails,
  mlController.getDetails,
  mlController.uploadData
  )
```

**MlController.js**

````
async function getAPIData(req, res, next) {
  try {

    let loanboardapi = " ", dealersocket = " ";
    loanboardapi = {
      url: "https://loanboard.houstondirectauto.com/api/User/GetAuthorizationToken?username=amin@houstondirectauto.com&password=test@123",
      method: "GET"
    };
    dealersocket = {
      url: 'https://idms.dealersocket.com/api/authenticate/GetUserAuthorizationToken?username=ankur@houstondirectauto.com&password=H5d465@!ddfdd45dsfd688&InstitutionID=105815',
      method: 'GET'
    };
    request(loanboardapi,
      (err, res, body) => {
       console.log("res = ", res);
        console.log("body =", body);
        loantoken = JSON.parse(body).token;
        console.log(loantoken);

      });
    request(dealersocket,
      (err, res, body) => {
        console.log("res = ", res);
        console.log("body =", body);
        dealertoken = JSON.parse(body).Token;
        console.log(dealertoken);
         next();
      });

  }
  catch (e) {
    req.error = e;
    next();
  }
}
 function getData(req, res, next) {
  try {

    let result;

    request.get('https://idms.dealersocket.com/api/account/getaccountlist?token=' + dealertoken + '&LayoutID=2002313&PageNumber=1&accounttype=i&accountstatus=a,c,b,o,r,s,x',
      (err, res, body) => {
        console.log("res = ", res);
        console.log("body =", body);
        result = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(result);
        totalpage = parseInt(result.TotalPages);
        let resultdata = Object.assign({}, result.Data);
        console.log(resultdata);
        //getSSN(totalpage, dealertoken, next);
         next();
        
      })
  }
  catch (e) {
    req.error = e;
    next();
  }
}
async function getCRCDetails(req,res,next) {
  async.eachSeries(ssn, async (item) => {
    let CBCOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      url: "https://loanboard.houstondirectauto.com/api/Report",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Cookie: "ci_session=udmojmlc5tfl3epbrmtvgu6nao2f031p",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        token: loantoken,
        action: "CBCReport",
        variables: {
          ssn: item,
        },
      }),
    };
    let EMpInfoption = {
      method: "POST",
      url: "https://loanboard.houstondirectauto.com/api/Report",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Cookie: "ci_session=udmojmlc5tfl3epbrmtvgu6nao2f031p",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        token: loantoken,
        action: "getEmployerInfo",
        variables: {
          ssn: item,
        },
      }),
    };
    try {
      let resultCBCOptions = await requestpromise(CBCOptions);
      let EmployerInfoOptions = await requestpromise(EMpInfoption);
      console.log(resultCBCOptions)
      console.log(EmployerInfoOptions)
      CRCOptions.push(resultCBCOptions);
      EmpOption.push(EmployerInfoOptions);
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
  () => {
  
     next();
  }
);

}
async function getDetails(req,res,next) {
  for(let i =0;i<CRCOptions.length;i++){
      for(let j=0;j<EmpOption.length;j++){
        let resdata = JSON.parse(CRCOptions[i]);
        console.log(resdata);
        result = resdata.data.DigifiResponse;
        console.log(result);
        
        let bodydata = JSON.parse(EmpOption[i]).data;
        
       let crcssn = JSON.parse(CRCOptions[i]).ssn;
       let empssn = JSON.parse(EmpOption[i]).ssn;
       console.log("CRCSSN=",crcssn);
       console.log("EMPSSN=",empssn);
       if(crcssn == empssn)
         {
          for(let r=0;r<result.length;r++){
            let crcdata = result[r];
            console.log(crcdata);
            for(let b=0;b<bodydata.length;b++) {
              let annual_income;
               console.log(bodydata[b]);
                let mergedata = Object.assign(crcdata, bodydata[b]);
                console.log("merge", mergedata);
                if (mergedata["IncomeFrequency"] == "Monthly") {
                  annual_income = (parseInt(mergedata["Income"]) * 12).toString();
                  console.log(annual_income);
                }
                else {
                  annual_income = mergedata["Income"];
                }
                let binary = {
                  "accounts_opened": mergedata["total_number_of_open_accounts"],
                  "bankruptcies": mergedata["total_number_of_bankruptcies"],
                  "collections": mergedata["total_number_of_collections"],
                  "credit_inquiries_last_6_months": mergedata["total_number_of_inquires_in_the_last_6_months"],
                  "past_due_accounts": mergedata["total_number_of_accounts_currently_past_due"],
                  "open_accounts": mergedata["total_number_of_open_accounts"],
                  "high_credit_limit": mergedata["total_credit_limit_amount"],
                  "annual_income": annual_income
                }
                console.log(binary);
                let arraybinary = Object.assign({},binary);
                console.log(arraybinary);
                binarydata.push(arraybinary);
                console.log(binarydata);

                let categorical = {
                  "bankruptcies_last_18_months": mergedata["count_of_bankruptcies_last_24_months"],
                  "credit_inquiries_last_6_months": mergedata["count_of_auto_loan_inquiries_last_9_months"],
                  "months_since_most_recent_inquiry": mergedata["total_number_of_inquires_in_the_last_6_months"],
                  "ninety_plus_delinquencies_last_18_months": mergedata["total_number_of_accounts_with_90180_day_delinquencies"],
                  "number_of_accounts_currently_30dpd": mergedata["total_number_of_accounts_with_3059_day_delinquencies"],
                  "open_credit_accounts": mergedata["total_number_of_open_auto_accounts"],
                  "pre_loan_debt_to_income": mergedata["total_amount_of_credit_debt"],
                  "total_current_balance": mergedata["total_account_balance"],
                  "total_high_credit_limit": mergedata["total_credit_limit_amount"],
                  "annual_income": annual_income
                }
                console.log(categorical);
                let arraycategory = Object.assign({},categorical);
                console.log(arraycategory);
                categoricaldata.push(arraycategory);
                let Linear = {
                  "bankruptcies_last_18_months": mergedata["count_of_bankruptcies_last_24_months"],
                  "credit_inquiries_last_6_months": mergedata["count_of_auto_loan_inquiries_last_9_months"],
                  "months_since_most_recent_inquiry": mergedata["total_number_of_inquires_in_the_last_6_months"],
                  "ninety_plus_delinquencies_last_18_months": mergedata["total_number_of_accounts_with_90180_day_delinquencies"],
                  "number_of_accounts_currently_30dpd": mergedata["total_number_of_accounts_with_3059_day_delinquencies"],
                  "open_credit_accounts": mergedata["total_number_of_open_auto_accounts"],
                  "pre_loan_debt_to_income": mergedata["total_amount_of_credit_debt"],
                  "total_current_balance": mergedata["total_account_balance"],
                  "total_high_credit_limit": mergedata["total_credit_limit_amount"],
                  "annual_income": annual_income
                }
                console.log(Linear);
                let arraylinear = Object.assign({},Linear);
                console.log(arraylinear);
                Lineardata.push(arraylinear);
            }
          }
         }
         break;
      }
  } 
  console.log(binarydata.length);
  console.log(binarydata);
  converter.json2csv(binarydata,(err,csv) => {
    if(err)throw err;
    console.log(csv);
    file.writeFileSync('/home/rita_gatistavam/Downloads/CSV/binarydata.csv',csv);
    console.log('File Written');
  })
  converter.json2csv(Lineardata,(err,csv) => {
    if(err)throw err;
    console.log(csv);
    file.writeFileSync('/home/rita_gatistavam/Downloads/CSV/lineardata.csv',csv);
    console.log('File Written');
  })
  converter.json2csv(categoricaldata,(err,csv) => {
    if(err)throw err;
    console.log(csv);
    file.writeFileSync('/home/rita_gatistavam/Downloads/CSV/categorydata.csv',csv);
    console.log('File Written');
  })
   next();
}
async function  uploadData(req,res,next){
let moduletype = sessionStorage.getItem('moduletype');
console.log(moduletype);

 req.params.id = sessionStorage.getItem('modelid');
 console.log(req.params.id);
 try {
  
  res.status(200).send({
    status: 200,
    timeout: 10000,
    type: 'success',
    text: 'Changes saved successfully!',
    successProps: {
      successCallback: 'func:window.createNotification',
    },
    responseCallback: 'func:this.props.reduxRouter.push',
    pathname: `/ml/models/${req.params.id}/training/historical_data_${moduletype}`,
  });
  
} catch (e) {
  periodic.logger.warn(e.message);
  res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error updating model type.', });
}

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Cannot understand your question, but I assume you want to get all the async request in one go.

You can achieve this with Promise.all, all the results will be returned as an array, and all the request will run at the same time.

```
const results = await Promise.all([asyncRequest1, asyncRequest2, asyncRequest3])
```

getting resulsts sequentially.

```
await asyncRequest1();
await asyncRequest2();
await asyncRequest3();
```

Comment: Hi @Someone Special ,Actually currently when API is calling all the method works on one time due to async method so need to call all methods one by one means untill the process of first method is not complete can not move on another method. how  can I do that in node js?

Comment: But I call methods with pagename like mlcontroller.asyncRequest1() then where I put await keyword during the call? look at my code.

Comment: i don't understand what you want. Those are routes, so they are accessed individually isn't it? Routes are routes, methods are methods, please figure out what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want that when api is call then all the methods call under that API is currently call simulteniously instead of that I need to call all the methods one by one means as per code untill process of getAPI() is not complete its process not go to next method and further same condition works for further methods.

Comment: Means Under API call next method call after complete process of previous method.

Comment: is this code written by you? A route is a route, when u call /api/somefunction, only somefunction route is called. If you want multiple functions to be called, then break them up into callable functions

Comment: You may want to update your question, show us what's the results you getting now, and what's the desirable results you want. That will be clearer.

Comment: when data_source_upload API call
 At that time First getAPIData() method call in which I will take token for another 2 API's 
after that call getData() in which I will pass both token to related API.and get the result.

Comment: after that call getCRCDetails() in which from the result (result have multiple array with object in which ssn number is exist) so loop on ssn number but in this method approx 4500 ssn number exist so this method takes only 100 ssn number at one time process and pass to next method and then second time take another 100 ssn number where I need that it takes 4500 ssn number will take by this method at one time and then move to next method.

Comment: then don't put next() in catch, u should put next in try .

Comment: I apply next in try also but not get the solution its works like after 100 records on one time and move to next() and pass on next method.